# Bootstrap Navbar - Add <hr> before and after links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar. When a dropdown is expanded I would like to add a line break  line under the dropdown and the last item in the list.

I have made a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/jFVBwx4Lcj) and attached an image to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

[image]

Here is my jQuery.

```
$('.dropdown.open .dropdown-toggle').append('<hr class="break-sec-w">');
```

Comment: Can't you just use the `<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>` element ?

Comment: `I would like to add a line break line under the dropdown first child and the last.` That does not make sense, your picture says you want to add it to the last child of the dropdown and to the dropdown link itself.

Comment: badly frased the dropdown and the last child...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your hr should be wrapped within a div to take effect.

I tried modifying your code--
Try the dropdowns

**Example**

```js
 $(document).ready(function($) {   

$('.hr_line').append('<hr class="break-sec-w">');
  
  });
```

```css
 .break-sec-w {
    width: 40px;
    
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    margin-top: 10px !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
     
       </head>
       <body>
       
       <div class="container">

      <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
         
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              
             
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                   <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              
                       <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              
             
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                   <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
                       <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                   <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              
             
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                   <li><div class="hr_line"></div></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>



    </div> <!-- /container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Answer (score 0):

You could try CSS styling. nth-child

```
.nav> li:nth-child(2),
.nav> li:nth-child(7) {
    content: "<hr>"
```

}

You may need to change the classes  which i have used in the example.

Comment: `:first-child/:last-child` would be a better choice.

Comment: interesting i tried something like this but i had no luck, how can i insert the HR with a class like this..

Comment: @user1673498, Why do you need an `<hr>` when you can simply use a `border`?

Comment: yeah border would be just as easy.

Comment: problem with border is that it takes the full width of the link and actually my illustration is wrong the line should be a lot smaller. ill update

Answer (score 0):

You can override some css if you need some extra styling such as:

```
.navbar-nav .open ul.dropdown-menu{ 
     border-radius:0px; 
     border:solid 1px red; 
     border-width:1px 0;
}
```

[Updated Bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/9aCP2Np6Ac)

Comment: This is good and simply, however the line goes full width and i need to be able to make it smaller..

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version based on your code, using just border:

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

hr.break-sec-w {
  width: 40px;
  /* color: #fff !important; */
  border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 10px !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
  position: static;
  float: none;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav {
  margin: 7.5px -15px;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover {
  color: #555;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#navbar a{
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown>a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown li:last-child a{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <!-- Static navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 2 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>


              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>


              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown 3 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>


              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
          <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>



</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Mm this has the line going across all the dropdowns and its full width, i need to be able to set the width of the line..

Comment: Use `display: inline-block` on the anchors. I'll update to show.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in many ways, but i'm pretty sure that you shouldn't use hr for that. Underline effect done via border, or after selectors will do the job :)

Examples with border:

1. Class for the element that needs to be separated from the rest and then css for that like

   .classname{
       border-bottom: 1px solid #colorHex;
    }
2. Select certain elements that needs to get the underline effect:

   .nav>li:nth-child(2),
      .nav>li:nth-child(7){
         border-bottom: 1px solid #colorHex;
      }

Example with the after selector:

```
.className{
   position: relative;
}
.className:after{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #yourHex
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using :after pseudo-element:

#### No javascript

```
.navbar-nav .open .dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: ' ';
    width: 10%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: red;
    display: block;
    margin: 5px auto;
}
```

here is [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/kUkjfxMRcS)